# Ошибка модуля в Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Работаю на Ubuntu. Установил  node.js, запускал програмы через консоль все работало. Запустил код ниже и выдало ошибку "**nodejs internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979**" и **"Error: Cannot find module '/home/bogdan/Downloads/Exersice/check.js'**"
Первый файл:

```
// Встроенный в Node.JS модуль для проверок
var assert = require('assert');

// Подключаем свою функцию
var sum = require('./index.js');

assert.equal(sum(12, 33), 45, 'При сложении 12 и 33 получится 45');
assert.equal(sum(101, '17'), 118, 'При сложении 101 и 17 получится 118');

console.info('OK!');
```

Второй:

```
/**
* @param {Number} a Первое слагаемое
* @param {Number} b Второе слагаемое
* @returns {Number}
*/
module.exports = function (a, b) {
   return Number(a) + Number(b);
};
```

Comment: Ну там же написано, что не может найти модуль. Наверное путь не правильно написал

Comment: Хм, а при чём здесь вообще файл check.js?

Comment: Похоже, вы где-то в другом месте подключали check.js, но потом удалили или переименовали